# How to get autocomplete working in visual studio code?

Tags: autocomplete

I don't see any code hints when i write code. i would like to see when i type Input. after the dot list of functions etc that i can use but i see nothing. i see only things that i wrote in that file but i don't see any unity classes or anything that i wrote using... at the top.
**How to get autocomplete working in visual studio code?**
I tried other code editors but none is working. Please help me I can't do anything without autocomplete my life is ruined.
Why isn't this quality standard?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> If you find IntelliSense has stopped working, the language service may
> not be running. Try restarting VS Code and this should solve the
> issue. If you are still missing IntelliSense features after installing
> a language extension, open an issue in the repository of the language
> extension.

See more in the [docs.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense)

Answer (score -1):

In Unity i click open c# project and than i have message project have trouble loading

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 20.01.2021, 14:18:44
    Target: c:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\New Unity Project\New Unity Project.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 2760

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on Windows 6.2.9200.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 16.8.0 - "c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to 'c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.8.0 - "c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            CscToolPath = c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild
            MSBuildToolsPath = c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 110
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.BlockStructureWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 140
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in 'c:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\New Unity Project'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        Detecting projects in 'c:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\New Unity Project\New Unity Project.sln'.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for 'c:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\New Unity Project\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in 'c:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\New Unity Project'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location 'c:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\New Unity Project' on host 10176.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: c:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\New Unity Project\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.Timeline.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.VSCode.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'UnityEngine.UI.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.Timeline.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.CollabProxy.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.Rider.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Sprite.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Tilemap.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'Unity.TextMeshPro.csproj' does not exist.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The referenced project 'UnityEditor.UI.csproj' does not exist.
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file 'c:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\New Unity Project\Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
c:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\New Unity Project\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1889,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.Timeline.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1889,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.VSCode.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1889,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1889,5): Error: The referenced project 'UnityEngine.UI.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1889,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.Timeline.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1889,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.CollabProxy.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1889,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.Rider.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1889,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Sprite.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1889,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.2D.Tilemap.Editor.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1889,5): Error: The referenced project 'Unity.TextMeshPro.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1889,5): Error: The referenced project 'UnityEditor.UI.csproj' does not exist.
c:\Users\Mateusz\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.8\.omnisharp\1.37.6-beta.30\.msbuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1180,5): Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: c:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\New Unity Project\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Completion.CompletionService
        Could not find document for file c:\Users\Mateusz\Desktop\New Unity Project\Assets\sc.cs
```